# Transferring the concepts "string" and "character" into TeX/LaTeX

Tags: characters, strings, tex-general

*(Looking at packages like **l3string**, **xstring** and **stringstrings** tempted me to post the following: )*

The concepts "string" and "character" to me seem not well defined in (La)TeX.
Because:

1. LaTeX has different stages of processing and it is not always clear which stage of processing the terms "string" and "character" refer to.
   Issues are, e.g.:

   - In case they refer to characters of the .tex-input-file it often comes to having things tokenized in verbatim-mode.
   - In the stage of macro expansion these concepts might refer to (sequences of) explicit character tokens whereof each can be processed as an undelimited macro argument.
   - Shall a ligature be taken for several characters or is it a single character of the string?
   - What about things like `\hbox{A}` which when processed in  horizontal mode yield in the output-file a single character?
2. In the stage of processing/expanding macros LaTeX works in terms of tokens (character tokens and control sequence tokens) and detecting what token-sequence forms a character is not trivial.
   Issues are, e.g.:

   - Multibyte-encoding on 8-bit-engine yields a single multibyte-character character being represented by several engine-native character-tokens;
   - Different notations/token-constellations may yield accented letters/Umlauts and the like;
   - `\char`-notation;
   - The need of doubling category-6-hashes when defining macros whose expansion is to yield a string which also contains hashes;
   - Presence of tokens that don't necessarily yield visible output, e.g., category 1/2-braces of a scoping-group;
   - Presence of tokens that denote material that at the level of visual output in the pdf-file does not refer to the concepts "string" and "character" at all, e.g., directives for drawing rules, inserting kern/glue, including graphics, performing assignments, local scoping, ...
   - Creation of a "string" of repeated character-sequences via `\leaders`;
   - ...
3. Often, the concepts "character" and "string" are also to be put in relation to concepts like "grapheme" and "constellations of glyphes".
   E.g.: Under which conditions are things that can be components of diacritical marks—⁠for example trema of umlauts, accents⁠—to be considered "characters" on their own?
4. The purpose for which the "string" in question is to be used is relevant also.
   E.g.,:

   - Usage within `\csname..\endcsname`.
   - Name/identifier of a piece of data when (ab?)using TeX for maintaining some sort of database—databases via the package **datatool**; writing external .csv-files; the .aux-file of LaTeX can be considered some sort of database (the `\@writefile`-entries therein make up a database, the `\newlabel`-entries therein make up a database).
   - Something that is to be typeset.
   - pdf-encoded string.
   - Name of a target/anchor/destination for hyperlinking.
   - pdf-bookmark.
   - ...

Whenever I try to transfer the concepts "String" and "Character" into TeX/LaTeX, e.g., to implement a routine that detects the length of a string or extracts some "character" from a "string" or checks whether some strings are to be considered "equal", I have the feeling that I have to make some cutbacks and that I might not even consider everything that is worth considering.

Are there any papers that provide a good (theoretical) overview of the topic "transferring the concepts 'string' and 'character' into TeX/LaTeX" and of the issues involved and suggesting how to deal with these issues?

Comment: if doing this now probaby best to also align with expl3 terminoligy `str` = string =catcode 10 or 12, `char`(acter) are character tokens. `text` is (as far as possible) Unicode text

Comment: Precisely because it's not well-defined, then it's necessary to explicitly define it when the term is used...? (e.g. expl3 does explicitly define it. For packages like xstring I guess it's not made very clear because the intended reader is "users", but in that case the programmers will complain like what you did above)

Comment: If you want to think in C terms, a character in TeX is a data structure and a string is a linked list.